# "/usr/bin/ping" is shown as yellow-on-red in the default Fedora bash color scheme -- what does it mean?

Tags: ls, colors, ping

When listing the directory `/usr/bin`, one sees that  `ping`  is shown as yellow-on-red:

[image: ping shown yellow-on-red]

The file has no special features:

```
$ file /usr/bin/ping
/usr/bin/ping: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for
GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=2508ea2a85b70c68967b3e6345541430f5317d5f,
stripped

$ stat /usr/bin/ping
   File: '/usr/bin/ping'
   Size: 62096           Blocks: 136        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 4457229     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:ping_exec_t:s0
Access: 2016-11-01 10:02:57.332925719 +0100
Modify: 2016-06-22 14:01:14.000000000 +0200
Change: 2016-07-10 23:41:59.623796126 +0200
Birth: -
```

According to [What do the different colors mean in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-the-terminal), where we can find a script to list color interpretations, "yellow-on-red" means "ca":

[image: Colors seen in Fedora default bash coloring scheme]

What does "ca" mean? Maybe it means that this file is hardlinked from elsewhere (`/usr/bin/ping` and `/usr/ping` are the same file)

P.S. The question occurred while watching [Explaining Dirty COW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEsshExn7aE), where the `ping` command on Ubuntu is show as setuid root, which sounds weird:

[image: setuid root ping]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This indicates that `ping` has extra capabilities:

```
$ getcap /usr/bin/ping
/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep
```

or even (on Fedora up to 30):

```
$ getcap /usr/bin/ping
/usr/bin/ping = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep
```

This allows `ping` to open a raw socket (and send and receive ICMP packets) without running as `root`. [`setcap(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html) and [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) give more details.

Historically, `ping` was installed setuid so that it would run as `root` and be able to use raw sockets; once capabilities became usable, many distributions switched to using those instead, since the finer-grained control they offer over permissions seems preferable. In Ubuntu though, [there are issues apparently with the installer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iputils/+bug/1302192), so `ping` is still installed setuid `root` (the capabilities code is disabled in [the relevant maintainer script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/iputils/wily/view/head:/debian/iputils-ping.postinst), which comes from Debian where `ping` is configured [using capabilities](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/iputils.git/tree/debian/iputils-ping.postinst) if possible).

The `ping` manpage [describes its requirements](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ping.8.html#SECURITY) thus:

> `ping` requires `CAP_NET_RAW` capability to be executed 1) if the program is used for non-echo queries (See `-N` option),  or
> 2)  if  kernel  does  not support non-raw ICMP sockets, or 3) if the user is not allowed to create an ICMP echo socket.
> The program may be used as set-uid root.

Kernels 2.6.39 and later provide [another mechanism to allow programs to send and receive ICMP echo messages](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c319b4d76b9e583a5d88d6bf190e079c4e43213d): [`net.ipv4.ping_group_range`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/ip-sysctl.html). This is used in Fedora 31 and later to allow `ping` to work without extra capabilities (notably, inside rootless containers); see [How does ping work on Fedora without setuid and capabilities?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/592911/86440) for details.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. My system knowledge is weak! I didn't even know capabilities existed, and they have been in there since kernel 2.2 ... [January 26, 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Releases_before_2.6.0). According to the `capabilities(7)` man page, _No  standards  govern  capabilities,  but  the Linux capability implementation is based on the withdrawn POSIX.1e draft standard; see [here](http://wt.tuxomania.net/publications/posix.1e/)_

Comment: His screen snapshot indicates suid root.

Comment: @Joshua in Ubuntu yes, but the question is about Fedora (first screenshot).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the reason for setuid root on another system is the same (to be able to send and receive ICMP packets) just via a less fine-grained permission.

Comment: Thanks @KevinReid, I've added that to my answer. (The Ubuntu explanation is a bit more complex than I thought it would be!)

Comment: Starting with Fedora 31, `/usr/bin/ping` no longer needs extra capabilities like `CAT_NET_RAW`. [Discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/592911).